# Referencing IBM.Data.Informix dll for .NET FW 2.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, informix

I am working on a mobile application that needs to connect to an Informix DB, I am developing using Visual Studio 2008, Windows mobile SDK 6.0, .NET Compact framework 3.5. and I referenced IBM.Data.Informix dll (v 2.0) to use the ADO.NET driver in it.

When deploying the application, the compiler asked me to reference System.dll (v 2.0) and System.Data (v 2.0) and after referencing them my application takes too much space about (35 MB) and my device memory went out of space, because it loads many other libraries like System.Web.dll which take too much space.

Any help please about how to reference IBM.Data.Informix dll correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use desktop assemblies on the device, even if you had room for them.  You'll need to either find a CF-compiled Informix assembly or create one.

Answer (score 1):

The informix .Net driver need that the native drivers be installed in the machine (the CSDK)
And because of that you can use the driver in a mobile device or in another computer copying only the assemblies

Comment: Where to find those assemblies, please?

Comment: I'm only aware of the Assemblies in the CSDK and I think those are the ones you are trying to use.